# ¿Cómo liberar memoria? (VBA)

Tags: vba

Estoy programando en VBA y me está ocurriendo un problema con el consumo de memoria pues, en la lista de procesos de Windows, Excel llega a 66 MB antes del proceso, y luego crece a 1680 MB después del proceso.

```
Sub NEW_CED()
'   Ctrl+Shift+C

            'INICIA LAS VENTANAS
    New_document.Show

    Worksheets("BASE_CÉDULAS").Select
            'ELIMINACIÓN DE FORMATO CONDICIONAL
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

            'INICIALIZACIÓN DE FILA
    Rows("500:500").Select  '500 es un número cualesquiera. Realmente, no importa
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

            'ASIGNACIÓN DE VALORES
    With Worksheets("BASE_CÉDULAS")
        .Range("A500").Value = New_document.documentNumber.Text
        .Range("B500").Value = New_document.lastNames.Text + " " + New_document.names.Text
        .Range("C500").Value = New_document.document.Text
        .Range("D500").Value = New_document_2.expeditionCity.Text 'Este form se inicializa desde New_document
            'ORDENAR Y FILTRAR
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A12674"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Range("A1:AD12674")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
            'RE-APLICAR FORMATO CONDICIONAL
        .Columns("A:D").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1=$A2"
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .Cells.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
            'BUSCAR Y SELECCIONAR
        .Columns(1).Find(What:=New_document.documentNumber.Text, _
                                    After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                                    SearchFormat:=False).Select

    End With

    Unload New_document
    Unload New_document_2
End Sub
```

Pongo todo el código porque ni siquiera entiendo porqué es tan alto el consumo. La mayor parte del código se basa en grabación de macro. Agradezco de antemano al que pueda ayudarme...

Especificaciones:

- Windows 7 Home Basic (32 bits)
- Intel Celeron CPU G1610 2.6 GHz
- 4.00 GB de RAM

Comment: Que el codigo provenga del grabador no implica que sea mas liviano, es importante aclarar que estas ejecutando varios temas sobre rangos extensos como aplicación de formatos y sobre todo formulación, para luego hacer busquedas sobre campos formulados (a mi parecer, es muy probable que en la busqueda final es donde mas memoria estes consumiendo). Mi sugerencia es que empieces a ejecutar por bloques la macro, es decir, ve removiendo bloques del codigo y probando mientras revisas el estado de la memoria, por descarte llegaras a el bloque que mas consume recursos del equipo y podras determinar com

Answer (score 2):

Otra cosa que podrías hacer es generar macros mas pequeñas, es decir, tu macro la particiones en pasos que quieras que se vayan ejecutando en secuencia, para ésto, en la primera macro deberas colocar:

```
call nombredelasiguientemacro()
```

Answer (score 2):

Buenas noches mi estimado;

Hace falta más información para entender al 100% que esperas traer de New_document y como lo trabajas. Sin embargo veo algunas partes de código que puedes simplificar ya que al ser grabada son ineficientes y pueden ayudarte a consumir menos memoria:

1.- En asignación de valores no necesitas poner `With Worksheets("BASE_CÉDULAS")` porque ya seleccionaste la hoja algunas líneas antes; Puedes trabajar con `Range("A500").Value =...` normalmente ya que todo lo realizas en la misma hoja seleccionada.

2.- `Sort` tampoco necesita el `With .Sort` debería estar escrito:

```
Range("A2:A12674").sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

la línea está aplicando el ordenado del rango `"A2:A12674"` de forma ascendente y respetando `A2` como header o título de columna en caso de que `A1` sea la cabecera de la tabla cambia los dos `A2` por `A1`.

3.- Para `RE-APLICAR FORMATO CONDICIONAL` tampoco necesitas que esté dentro de un `with` déjalo de la siguiente forma:

```
        'RE-APLICAR FORMATO CONDICIONAL
        Columns("A:D").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1=$A2"
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 65535
        Cells.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

En resumen no necesitas los with por trabajar siempre sobre la misma hoja y puede ser este el motivo por el que usas tanta memoria si puedo ayudarte en algo más con gusto espero tus comentarios.

Saludos!!!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con poner esto al princio

```
    screenUpdateStatus = Application.ScreenUpdating
    statusBarStatus = Application.DisplayStatusBar
    calcStatus = Application.Calculation
    eventsStatus = Application.EnableEvents
    displayPageBreakStatus = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Y al final esto

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdateState
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = calcState
Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = displayPageBreaksState
```